# How to install The Maitre D in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Ever heard of the game "The Maitre D"? Probably not. Anyways I need help installing it on Ubuntu KDE. I can't get it to run. It is a tar.gz file. If you want to take a look at the game go to https://powerhoof.itch.io/the-maitre-d

Comment: If you can answer, please do. **Thanks!!**

Answer (score 1):

What's the exact problem? Seems to work for me just fine. Here is the process I followed:

1. [Download](https://powerhoof.itch.io/the-maitre-d)
2. Extract (use right click and extract or use `tar -zxvf TheMaitreD-linux.tar.gz`)
3. open terminal and change directory using `cd` to extracted folder
4. run `chmod +x TheMaitreD.x86_64`
5. Enjoy the game!!

Comment: Alright, please mark it as answer for the future reference!